# Packaging The configuration of an Encryption Scheme -- Hopefully using just OpenSSL

Tags: configuration, cryptography, openssl

I have a encryption scheme implemented, the constituent components: The symetric cypher and its chaining mode, and the HMAC algorithm are hard-coded into the binary. Additionally, the parameters of the algorithms (HMAC key, symetric-key symetric IVEC) are specified in binary files, one for each parameter.

I would like to specify the choice of algorithms, and modes, and their parameters in a single file. Do I need my own format, or is this possible using existing OpenSSL infrastructure ? If there is infrastructure, could someone please provide some references.

p.s., I know of the config file parsing code, and the PEM/x.509 code in OpenSSL. However anything built from this won't be cohesive.

Comment: Can't you simply script it? You can certainly put values and multiple calls + configuration parameters into a script.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to specify the choice of algorithms, and modes, and their
>   parameters in a single file

That type of agility sounds like you will allow the user to make a choice. Don't do it, since they might pick a bad cipher (or cipher combination). Make good choices for them.

> The symetric cypher and its chaining mode, and the HMAC algorithm are
>   hard-coded into the binary.

I would first look into an authenticated encryption mode - EAX, CCM, or GCM. I believe OpenSSL only has CCM at the moment (or is it GCM?). If you can't use an authenticated encrpytion mode, move on to Encrypt-Then-Authenticate (ie, encrypt then authnticate the cipher text with a HMAC or CMAC), which it sounds like you are doing.

> Additionally, the parameters of the algorithms (HMAC key, symetric-key
>   symetric IVEC)

HMAC (and CMAC) are good. Don't use a CBC-MAC since it suffers from weaknesses on variable length messages.

> symetric-key [in binary file]

Hmmm...

> symmetric IVEC

IVs are considered public parameters. Pick a random IV for the message, and send it along with the cipher text. Make sure to MAC both the cipher text and IV to detect tampering.

> Do I need my own format, or is this possible using existing OpenSSL infrastructure

Look at [BIO](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bio.html)s for I/O. The encoding is up to you. You can write out raw bytes, you could Base{16|32|64} encode it, you can encode and store it in XML, or store it as name/value pairs.